# RYYCy bayer pattern to RGB image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rgb, color-conversion

I am looking for a solution to convert images with an RYYCy (Red, Yellow, Yellow, Cyan) bayer pattern to RGB. So far, I could only find solutions for different combinations of RGGB.

Does someone know a solution or open-source implementation? Or is there a straight-forward way to first convert RYYCy to RGGB and then apply the debayering?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Use RGGB demosaicing, and get Red, Yellow, Cyan components per each pixels. Then compute the green and the blue as in [CMY to RGB conversion formula](http://www.huevaluechroma.com/092.php). I don't know if it's going to work. Try making an effort and share a sample input (you may share it using Google Drive).

Comment: Hi @Rotem, thanks for your support. Unfortunately, I cannot share a sample input yet, as it is a future project and I do not have the cameras installed yet. It was just a general question I wanted to check in advance already before hardware setup.

Comment: You may post a simulated RYYCy input. With the simulated input my suggested solution is probably going to work. I don't think I am able to answer the general question about the future project.